# Showstringspaces in inline listing not showing

Tags: listings

I'm having trouble with `showstringspaces` in the listings package, setting the option to true seems to be being completely ignored.

My objective is to highlight the spaces in the strings using `\inlinetext` but currently the output looks like the below:

[image: What it looks like]

Am I missing something? Why is `showstringspaces` not having any effect?

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}  

% Color
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}

% Code
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand*{\inlinetext}{\lstinline[language=textwithspaces,showstringspaces=true,style=showspaces]}

\lstdefinestyle{showspaces}{
  basicstyle      = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  upquote=true,
  showstringspaces=true
}

\lstdefinelanguage{textwithspaces}{
    alsoletter={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,/,:},
    showstringspaces=true,
    style=showspaces
}

\begin{document}  

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Raw Transactor Name & Occurrences \\
\inlinetext$TESCO STORES 5128$   & 87         \\
\inlinetext$TESCO STORES 2977$   & 68         \\
\inlinetext$TESCO_STORES$        & 14         \\
\inlinetext$SACAT MARKS AND$     & 33         \\
\inlinetext$SACAT MARKS  AND$    & 16         \\
\inlinetext$WILKINSON $          & 22         \\
\inlinetext$WILKINSON$           & 8         
\end{tabular}
\label{table:cleaningstrings}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've realised this is probably something to do with listings not reading the text as a string literal and so not applying string spaces. I'm trying to find a way to use `morestring` to match all text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why no visible-space characters are shown is that `showstringspaces` key only shows visible spaces in string literals, and neither your custom style nor your custom language define what should be treated as strings in your listings. It seems you want to show visible spaces everywhere; in that case, as you correctly guessed, you should use `showspaces` instead.

### A couple of tips

(too long to leave in a TeX.SX comment):

1. **`style` and `language` are semantically different.** In most cases, a `listings` language should be used only to define what a language *is* (keywords, string delimiters, comments, etc.). In contrast, a `listings` style should only be used to define what a given language should *look like*. You should first define the language,  using keys such as `morekeywords`, `morestring`, `morecomment`, etc. Then, you should define the style by loading the newly defined language and customising the appearance, using keys such as `basicstyle`, `keyworstyle`, `stringstyle`, `commentstyle`, `showstringspaces`, etc. According to this rule, you are allowed to load a language within a style definition, but never the opposite, because a language is further up the `listings` hierarchy than a style is.
2. **Don't use the name *showspaces* for a new style.** You shouldn't define a style called `showspaces` because that is the name of a `listings` key. Such a name choice is probably safe (it shouldn't be associated with any side effects) but it has potential for confusion.
3. **Load the language first, customise the look later.** When you define a style, load the associated language (or the base style) *first*, and customise the look only afterwards. Loading a language or a style "too late" has the potential to wipe out most of the current settings.
4. **Use a one-character shorthand for inline code.** If you use inline code throughout your document, you can save yourself some keystrokes by defining a one-character shorthand for inline code in the style of your choice, using `listings`' `\lstMakeShortInline` macro (see subsection 4.17 in the documentation). Of course, you should use a character that is rarely/never used: if it occurs in other places in your `tex` file, you run the risk of utterly confusing TeX.

Here is how I think your code could be improved:

[image: screenshot of output]

```
\documentclass{article}  

% Color
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}

% Code
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{vizspaces-lang}{
  alsoletter={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,/,:}, % Is there a good reason for that?
}

\lstdefinestyle{vizspaces-sty}{
  language         = vizspaces-lang,
  basicstyle       = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
  breaklines       = true,
  showspaces       = true,
% showstringspaces = true, % (not needed if showspaces is set)
  upquote          = true,
}

\lstMakeShortInline[style=vizspaces-sty]"

\begin{document}  

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Raw Transactor Name & Occurrences  \\
"TESCO STORES 5128"   & 87         \\
"TESCO STORES 2977"   & 68         \\
"TESCO_STORES"        & 14         \\
"SACAT MARKS AND"     & 33         \\
"SACAT MARKS  AND"    & 16         \\
"WILKINSON "          & 22         \\
"WILKINSON"           & 8         
\end{tabular}
\label{table:cleaningstrings}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered my mistake, what I hinted at in my comment was right, listings was not treating the text as a string. However I found the option `showspaces=true` which shows spaces found anywhere in the listing and does exactly what I wanted.

[image: Text with spaces]